# Windows PC performance issues

Tags: windows-10, performance, reinstall, overheating

Since a few weeks ago I've been experiencing severe performance issues on Windows and possibly on Linux.

My self-built system contains:

- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz (Stock Cooler)
- Mobo: MSI B85-G41 PC Moate(MS-7850)
- RAM: 8GB, 2 Sticks, Kingston KHX1600C9D3K2/8GX
- GPU: AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series
- Drives: 120GB SSD and 2TB HDD
  PSU: Some random 600W PSU from the Computer store where I got my Parts

The way I determined that my PC has performance issues, is that audio playback is severely impaired and games that should run with no issues are partially unplayable.

Audio:

When I play audio via my browser or Deezer (an audio streaming app) I get stuttering at random intervals.

Games:

Some games that previously ran with no issues have extreme lag. A game that I recently acquired and that according to the developer runs on lower spec hardware then my system has.

Troubleshooting:

I have reinstalled Windows on my main drive, but the second drive containing one partition with Windows data and one partition with Linux data was left untouched. The issue still persists, and I have no idea where this issue came from or why I still have it.

The issue happens on no load, CPU, RAM, GPU, storage and Ethernet are all not really used. Checking hardware didn't result in anything except my CPU temperature being 90° C. I'll check on that. I didn't install anything new. Probably Linux means that Linux has performance issues, but it's more of a gut feeling then anything I actually experienced.

Comment: Could it be because of system overheating? Looks like your thermal grease on CPU heat sink dried out. I'd also checked all fans. Especially CPU and Power supply. Have you added HDDs recently? Or maybe DVD drive?

Comment: It could be so many things. I guess you did check Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc) to see if everything is cool there, especially at the time when there is stuttering and lag? Enough RAM, enough disk space? You said "possibly Linux": Do you have the same problems if you run something CPU, memory or GPU intensive under Linux? Perhaps checking the hardware with the tools mentioned on https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-test-your-pc-for-failing-hardware/ could be an idea.

Comment: So the issue happens on no load, CPU, RAM, GPU, Storage and Ethernet are all not really Used. Checking Hardware ddid not result to anything except my CPU temp beeing 90 °C, ill check on that. I did not install anything new. Probably Linux means that Linux has performance issues but its more of a gut feeling then anything I actually experience.

Comment: @p0rc0_r0ss0 Thank you very much, This was almost the right answer. Opening my System up revealed that the Intel fastfix thingys had loosened and therefore, I basically ran without a CPU cooler. I now am back from 100°C to 50°C. Would you mind posting that as an answer becaus you diagnose was spot on.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP solved it himself by finding the CPU cooler was loose,, and fixing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastener on the CPU cooling block had loosened which means that the CPU was basically running without a cooler, and as a result it was overheating. CPU overheating was the cause of the performance issues, unplayable games and severely impaired audio playback.